# Using finite difference for a simple second order BVP

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences, python, programming

I'm trying to solve this BVP using the finite difference method
$$u_{xx}(x) +sin(x) = 0$$
with $u(0)=u(2\pi)=0$. When I solve it on python, I get the correct curve shape I expect, a sinusoidal one, but the magnitude is much lower than what I expect. I'd expect a maximum and minimum of $1$ and $-1$, but they come out very small, like ~$0.04$.

Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100 #number of nodes
L = 2.0*math.pi #length of x-axis
x = np.linspace(0.0,L,N)
h = L/N #step length
u = np.zeros(N) #solution vector


u[0] = 0.0
u[N-1] = 0.0

#solve
for j in range(10):
    for i in range(1,N-1):
        u[i] = (u[i-1]+u[i+1]+h**2*math.sin(x[i]))/2.0

plt.plot(x,u)
```

and here's the curve
[image: The curve I get]

So what causes the incorrect magnitude? I should get a regular $sin(x)$ curve

Comment: What is the '$\texttt{for j in range(10)}$' part for? And you can not solve it like this. When you call $\texttt{u[i+1]}$, you just call $\texttt{0}$.

Comment: @Meowdog The outer loop is a fixed point iteration. In the first pass, all the $u$'s are zero, but this results in a vector of $h^2/2 \sin(x_n)$ which then does something in the second pass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you haven't written down the discrete equation that you are trying to solve, which is a bit troubling. I think the discrete equation you want to use is probably

$$\frac{u_{n+1}-2u_n+u_{n-1}}{h^2}=-\sin(x_n)$$

for $n=1,2,\dots,N-1$ with $u_0=u_N=0$. This can be done with just a linear system solver easily enough, but if you want to use an iterative method, you can do, say, the Jacobi method. The iteration for the Jacobi method is

$$u_n^{(k+1)}=\frac{h^2 \sin(x_n) + u_{n-1}^{(k)} + u_{n+1}^{(k)}}{2}$$

which is not quite the same as what you implemented. What you did is actually Gauss-Seidel:

$$u_n^{(k+1)}=\frac{h^2 \sin(x_n) + u_{n-1}^{(k+1)} + u_{n+1}^{(k)}}{2}$$

which is usually a little bit faster than Jacobi.

But this will converge *extremely* slowly in this context. Indeed in the worst case the eigenvalues of the Jacobi iteration matrix with the largest magnitude are larger than 0.995 in absolute value, so Jacobi would need about $\frac{\log(\epsilon)}{\log(0.995)} \approx 200 \log(1/\epsilon)$ iterations to multiply the error by a factor of $\epsilon$. Gauss-Seidel is a little faster (I have forgotten exactly how much faster). The error that you committed in your initial guess is *exactly* the worst case scenario for Jacobi as well.

Comment: @MichaelB Not at all. Examples of other methods include "ordinary relaxation" (where the iteration procedure is just generating a numerical simulation of the heat equation and then take the last iteration), successive over-relaxation (SOR), among others. Try using SOR with $\omega$ just a little bit less than 2 (like $1.99$ or so) and see how it behaves...

Comment: Actually I see now that SOR will not do that great in that case, either.

Answer (score 2):

10 iterations is far too few for Jacobi method (or in general any linear method) to converge with any reasonable accuracy.

In fact, a quick experiment printing result every 200 iterations gives
$$
\begin{array}{c||c|c}
\text{iteration}&\text{max error }(+)&\text{max error }(-)\\\hline
200 & 0.461371 & -0.455683 \\\hline
400 & 0.223509 & -0.208337 \\\hline
600 & 0.116791 & -0.098056 \\\hline
800 & 0.068118 & -0.049773 \\\hline
1000 & 0.045499 & -0.029056 \\\hline
1200 & 0.034605 & -0.020533 \\\hline
1400 & 0.029090 & -0.017293 \\\hline
1600 & 0.026095 & -0.016330 \\\hline
1800 & 0.024342 & -0.016295 \\\hline
2000 & 0.023215 & -0.016601 \\\hline
&\dots&\\\hline
10000 & 0.019570 & -0.019567 \\\hline
&\dots&\\\hline
20000 & 0.019568 & -0.019568
\end{array}
$$
which shows how slowly Jacobi converges.

Comment: In fact, looking at the implementation, this s not Jacobi's method, it is Gauss-Seidel. But your conclusions stand.

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution is $u(x)=\sin x$, so you have good reason to be suspicious of your result. As a side note, it is much better to use implicit methods to solve this kind of BVP: The numerical solution $u=(u_1, \cdots, u_n)$ is the solution of a tridiagonal linear system. However, your fixed point iteration should work... You have probably not used enough iterations.